# Mongoose Mongo extra fields in document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I am using Mongoose ODM.  I have a collection and the document essentially has one field in it.  I will add more later perhaps.  So when I insert, it inserts fine and the data is there however so is a lot of other fields, like: isNew, error, activePaths, states, etc...looks like Mongoose object data, not sure why its going in though. Any ideas?

Comment: please provide a little bit of code, otherwise the question is to generic and it is hard give you good answers..

Answer (score 0):

That data is indeed data that Mongoose inserts for its correct operation. This data is used for instance to: do validation, only do saves when necessary (simply stated: when 1 or more 'paths' are dirty), registration of 'pre-save' hooks, etc.

No fear though, since the fields mongoose keeps aren't persisted to mongoDB. (use mongo CLI or other tools to inspect what's actually in the DB)

At all times you could check `yourdocument._doc` which holds that actual fields that are scheduled to be saved to mongo.